# The best technology to use when generating pictures/graphs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, graph

I want to generate some picture, graphs to be more specific.
I would like them to render in a webpage.

I figured out that it's fairly easy to generate graph as pictures using javascript and HTML5 canvas.

But I realized that this might not be a good option, because javascript renders at client's side and calculating the graph may be complicated.
Also when I want to insert other pictures into such graph, javacript will expect those other pictures somewhere on client's computer.

So I guess that I should generate the picture before loading the page and then render the page with the picture on it...if there are no mistakes in my assumptions.
And if so, what would be the best way to achieve that? I work with Ruby and rails for the web app.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Chart.JS](http://www.chartjs.org/) its a very strong library and sounds like what youre looking for.

Comment: I have. Also different ones in the past when dealing with similar difficulty.
The problem with Chart.JS is that it have hell of a functionality from the graph settings/customization perspective.
But I need the only one a really good and efficient algorithm to place nodes not to overwrite one another and place edges without overlapping anything as well.
But other than that it's pretty much a simple graph. Nothing fancy to it.

The hard part are the nodes and those I cant create the way I want in Chart.JS